LOGSTASH - Getting a syntax error on output - "Expected one of [ \\t\\r\\n], \”#\”, \”(\” at line"
I'm facing an issue when trying to run this logstash configuration that uses http_poller to run a query and then compare the results from it with a local data table on my pc.
Here's the output and the ERROR in it:

[2024-05-21T16:03:45,523][ERROR][logstash.agent ] Failed to execute action {:action=>LogStash::PipelineAction::Create/pipeline_id:logstash, :exception=>"LogStash::ConfigurationError", :message=>"Expected one of [ \t\r\n], "#", "(" at line 93, column 28 (byte 2170) after output {\r\n if [new_entries] == true ", :backtrace=>["C:/elastic-stack/logstash-8.13.2/logstash-core/lib/logstash/compiler.rb:32:in compile_imperative'", "org/logstash/execution/AbstractPipelineExt.java:239:in initialize'", "org/logstash/execution/AbstractPipelineExt.java:173:in initialize'", "C:/elastic-stack/logstash-8.13.2/logstash-core/lib/logstash/java_pipeline.rb:48:in initialize'", "org/jruby/RubyClass.java:931:in new'", "C:/elastic-stack/logstash-8.13.2/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline_action/create.rb:49:in execute'", "C:/elastic-stack/logstash-8.13.2/logstash-core/lib/logstash/agent.rb:386:in `block in converge_state'"]}

Here is my Logstash config, I have gone over my code multiple times but can't seem to find where I'm missing any of these characters specified in the output ERROR.
input {
  http_poller {
    urls => {
        es_data => {
        method => get
        url => "http://localhost:9200/earthquake-v2/_search"
        headers => {
          Accept => "application/json"
        }
        body => '{
          "sort": [
            {
              "DateTime": {
                "order": "desc"
              }
            }
          ],
          "query": {
            "match_all": {}
          },
          "size": 1
        }'
      }
    }
    request_timeout => 60
    schedule => { cron => "* * * * * UTC" }
    codec => "json"
    metadata_target => "http_poller_metadata"
  }
  file {
    path => "C:/elastic-stack/earthquakes.txt"
    start_position => "beginning"
    sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
  }
}

filter {
  if [path] {
    mutate {
      add_field => {
        "message" => "%{message}"
      }
    }
    dissect {
      mapping => {
        "message" => "%{DateTime},%{Latitude},%{Longitude},%{Depth},%{Magnitude},%{MagType},%{NbStations},%{Gap},%{Distance},%{RMS},%{Source},%{EventID}"
      }
    }
    date {
      match => ["DateTime", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"]
    }
  }

  if [http_poller_metadata] {
    aggregate {
      task_id => "es_data"
      code => "map['es_datetime'] ||= event.get('[hits][hits][0][_source][DateTime]')"
      map_action => "create"
    }
  }

  if [DateTime] {
    aggregate {
      task_id => "local_data"
      code => "
        datetimes = map['local_datetimes'] ||= []
        datetimes << event.get('DateTime')
      "
      map_action => "update"
    }
  }

  if [path] and [@metadata][end_of_file] {
    aggregate {
      task_id => "local_data"
      code => "
        es_datetime = execution.get('es_data')['es_datetime']
        local_datetimes = map['local_datetimes'] || []
        
        if local_datetimes.any? { |datetime| datetime > es_datetime }
          event.set('new_entries', true)
        else
          event.set('new_entries', false)
        end
      "
      push_previous_map_as_event => true
      end_of_task => true
    }
  }
}

output {
  if [new_entries] == true {
    elasticsearch {
      hosts => ["http://localhost:9200"]
      index => "earthquake-v3"
      document_type => "_doc"
      user => "elastic"
      password => ""
      template_name => "earthquake-2"
      template => "C:/elastic-stack/logstash-8.13.2/conf/earthquake-2.json"
      ssl_verification_mode => "none"
      ssl_enabled => false
      manage_template => false
      template_overwrite => true
    }
  }

  stdout {
    codec => rubydebug
  }
}

Thank you in advance!

Logstash accepts if statement as like:
output {
 if [new_entries]
    elasticsearch {
...

